# Workflow for adding Pipe Systems to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, pipe-network

I want to layout a concept design for a sewer main in QGIS.  I have a variety of background information:

1. Aerial Imagery
2. Services from various sources
3. DEM from LIDAR
4. Lot Boundaries

I want to layout the system to get the following functionality, if possible:

1. Identify direction
2. Sum lots (or more particulary a Loading) moving in a direction
3. Where pipes join, add the Loadings
4. Profile the pipes to assess grades

I want to start off on the right foot, and seek any guidance, if possible.

Comment: were we able to help you?

Comment: Hi Bill, I didnt end up pursuing the EPANET as it is a bit above my skill level (very basic!).  However it was useful to know what was available and what tools were available.  I come from an engineering background, and therefore am not a natural GIS user.  As such I found it useful to know if the software is appropriate for this.  Due to time pressures on porjects it is difficult to explore this further, but I hope that in the coming months I may be able to look into things further (hopefully before my next project starts!).  Thanks for your detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

### Epanet

Have a look at Epanet and the plugins for it in QGIS.

http://epanet.de/ghydraulics/index.html.en

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ghydraulic/

and there is another epanet connector in the Plugins Manager menu which I haven't had any experience with.

Whilst Epanet is for pressurised pipelines and it deals with different anaylsis to your interests, it deals with a lot of the same concepts.

For instance in GIS a point/node does not natively have an orientation and so GHydraulics deals with this (afaik) by using very small lines as nodes.

### General Method

Just some notes

- Whilst the DEM will be useful, it is hard for us to evaluate it without more information. Is the topography (i.e. the DEM) a rigorous indicator of the invert of sewer pipes or does the sewer line traverse ridges and gullies?
- to what resolution is the aerial image? Does it show a scar on the landscape of the buried sewer line or more likely the paving and landscape obscure the pipe alignment. Do you have to plot other services like roads?
- I'd be surprised if there is all this ancillary data available that there is not some existing schematic of the sewer alignment which shows direction of flow etc.
- Unless you want to create an entirely theoretical model, some real flow and elevation data would be important for your work to have value to most end users. I can imagine excavating to the surface of a sample of pipes and taking elevation measurements. There are a range of technologies for sampling flows in pipes and providing estimates of the loadings.

Comment: Another EPANET tool is the Processing plugin provider by Oslandia. http://www.oslandia.com/qgis-plugin-for-water-management-en.html and http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_epanet/ and https://github.com/Oslandia/qgis-epanet and